# Even simple f:setPropertyActionListener is always setting variable to null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Maybe I miss something but I really can't tell what's wrong with my code, I done this with very simple tutorial but my button still don't set variable in my bean.

I want to give it value of button value (so if button value is "Button" I want set my string variable to "Button".

This is my Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "lwDetailsBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LwDetailsBean {

public String listaWydan;

public String getListaWydan() {
    return listaWydan;
}

public void setListaWydan(String listaWydan) {
    this.listaWydan = listaWydan;
}
```

This is my xhtml code:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{item.listaWydan}" oncomplete="PF('test').show()">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item.listaWydan}" target="#{lwDetailsBean.listaWydan}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

I even try put fixed value, no effect:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{item.listaWydan}" oncomplete="PF('test').show()">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener value="ILW000022784" target="#{lwDetailsBean.listaWydan}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: `@SessionScoped` beans have to implement `Serializable`.

Comment: You mean to say that you've added a breakpoint/logger/stdout/whatever to the setter method and observed that it's always invoked, but that the argument is always `null`? Or did you observe/conclude/assume it in a different way?

Comment: I use this variable as parameter to another method, I use sys.out to check what it contains. Implementing Serializable didn't fix the problem

Comment: Why is `listaWydan` attribute public? Change it to private.

Comment: So, you have not checked if the setter method is called or not? You've only checked the variable by calling the getter from outside? This conflicts with what you're saying in the question title. Please add a breakpoint/logger/stdout to the setter method and verify if it's indeed always invoked with a `null` argument. If it turns out that the setter method is actually never invoked, then you need to reframe the question.